# How to create node in React JS similar to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nodes, contenteditable, spell-checking

I just build a spell checker functionality using contenteditable. Whenever the user keyup it'll be triggered. The wrong words will be wrapped with a mark tag. I have just done using javascript but I need to do it in the React way.

```js
let originalNode = document.createElement('p')
let textNode = document.createTextNode('Sri Lankan Tamil activists in Britain paid tribute to the victims of the Sri Lankan civil war on Friday by placing the national flower of Tamil')
originalNode.appendChild(textNode)
let str = 'Tamil'
let wholeWordRegExp = new RegExp('\\b' + str + '\\b')
let pos = textNode.nodeValue.search(wholeWordRegExp)
let newNode = textNode.splitText(pos)
let mark = document.createElement('mark')
mark.setAttribute("contenteditable", true)
textNode.parentNode.insertBefore(mark, newNode)
newNode.splitText(str.length)
mark.appendChild(newNode)
console.log(originalNode)
//console.log(originalNode.firstChild)
```

I just want the mark tag in React like below

```
let mark = React.createElement('mark', {contenteditable: true}, newNode)
```

Comment: In React, you should use HTML code rather than DOM.

Answer (score 0):

My Demo is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-a6csul).

```
  import React, { useState } from 'react';
  export default function Test(props) {
  const orgText="Sri Lankan Tamil activists in Britain paid tribute to the victims of the Sri Lankan civil war on Friday by placing the national flower of Tamil";
  const [textHTML,setTextHTML]=useState([orgText]);
  let handleChange = e => {
    
    let str=e.target.value.trim();
    let wholeWordRegExp = new RegExp('\\b' + str + '\\b')
    let pos=orgText.search(wholeWordRegExp)
    let temp=[];
    if (pos>-1){
      temp.push(orgText.substring(0,pos));
      temp.push(
        <mark
          key="gg"
          contentEditable={true}
          suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>
            {str}
        </mark>    
      )
      temp.push(orgText.substring(pos+str.length));
      setTextHTML(temp);
    }
  };
  return (
    <form>
      <p>
        {textHTML}
      </p>
      <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. but actually, you can get my exact scenario by replacing the `<p>{textHTML}</p>` with `<div contentEditable={true} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: textHTML}} suppressContentEditableWarning={true}></div>`

Comment: Thanks for your information, would you give me a tick if my answer works for you?